# How can I use Vim-style tabs with window panes inside them in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, browser-tabs, tabs, ide, vscode-extensions

In Vim, tabs are a level above window panes.

That means that each tab has its own set of split windows, which makes it easier to move back and forth between a general view of many files and a "zoomed-in" view of a single file.

[image: Switching tabs in vim]

VSCode seems to have a different tab management where tabs are a level *below* window panes. If I switch a tab, only the file in that pane gets switched.

[image: Switching tabs in VSCode]

I cannot seem to find a setting or extension to have Vim-style tab switching in VSCode. Is there anything that makes it work in a sane way?

Answer (score 1):

As of now this isn't possible but there is a PR in the backlog, hopefully they get on it soon

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143024